# Why the InfluxDB v2 configuration file do not work?

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

In InfluxDB v2, the config file is change. check below, it's a different from v1.
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/config-options/

and I now I configured the env variable.

```
[root@dele ~]# echo $INFLUXD_CONFIG_PATH
/etc/influxdb/
```

and I follow the fastnetmon influxdb integration as below:
https://fastnetmon.com/docs/influxdb_integration/

```
[root@dele ~]# ls /etc/influxdb/
config.toml
[root@dele ~]# more /etc/influxdb/config.toml
[[graphite]]
  enabled = true
  bind-address = ":2003"
  protocol = "tcp"
  consistency-level = "one"
  separator = "."
  batch-size = 5000 # will flush if this many points get buffered
  batch-timeout = "1s" # will flush at least this often even if we haven't hit buffer limit
  templates = [
    "fastnetmon.hosts.* app.measurement.cidr.direction.function.resource",
    "fastnetmon.networks.* app.measurement.cidr.direction.resource",
    "fastnetmon.total.* app.measurement.direction.resource"
  ]
```

now I restart influxdb and check opened ports, but do not find :2003:

```
[root@dele ~]# netstat -an 
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
...
tcp6       0      0 :::8086                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50001           0.0.0.0:*                          
raw6       0      0 :::58                   :::*                    7
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like Influx v2 Supports Graphite anymore
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/upgrade/v1-to-v2/manual-upgrade/#1x-configuration-groups-not-in-20.

That might be why it's not opening the port, if it's not looking at that portion of the config.